# How can I lock only device administrators setting

Tags: android, security, device-admin

I am working on security application. User can't uninstall the application without applying a correct password. I am on device administrator permission in app. But when user try to install app then he/she can uninstall app by deactivating device administrator setting.

I want when user activate device administrator setting then app set a password on device administrator. At the time of uninstalling it ask password then user show device administrator setting.

Can it be possible? If yes then please suggest me how can I do, if not then please give me some idea how can I prevent user to uninstall app.

Comment: did you try using native USBManager class to connect and enable Accessory mode?